# Session checking using javascript in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session, servlets

I have done session activation and deactivation using servlets using

```
HttpSession s = request.getSession(); 
s.setAttribute("uname", uname);
```

and deactivation in logout servlet using

```
HttpSession sess=  request.getSession();
sess.invalidate();
```

Now I want to check in my JSP  page that is session is activate or not?
So for this I want this checking using JavaScript . 
I have method to check this using simple JSP code but I want this using JavaScript's function. So that if session is activate then I will reload same page and if session is expired then it will redirect to the `login.jsp` page. So I could not get any idea about it.

Comment: you can make ajax call to check session.

Comment: Thansk@SanjayRajjadi .And hows that done?

Comment: you write a code to check the session in servlet and make ajax call to that servlet..I hope u get it.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how to call servlet using ajax. @SanjayRajjadi

Comment: you will have some idea from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788798/call-servlet-from-ajax

Comment: But its not working properly. Any other link for this? @SanjayRajjadi

Answer (score 0):

As for tomcat webservers the session is usually mantained by a cookie with name JSESSIONID. However from that cookie being set you can not be sure that the session is still valid. The only one who can tell you, having a valid session or not is the server. So it'll be better to do the redirect on the server.

Comment: But i want check on my jsp page using javascript, so can you please elaborate answer or give me any example or link that will help me to understand this. Thanks @Markus